why opcode create always returns zero address?
my 2 functions:
    function func1(bytes memory code) public {
        address addr;
        assembly {
            addr := create(callvalue(), add(code, 0x20), mload(code))
        }
        emit Deployed(addr);
    }

    function func2(bytes memory code) public {
        address addr;
        assembly {
            addr := create(callvalue(), add(code, 0x20), mload(code))
        }
        require(addr != address(0));
        emit Deployed(addr);
    }

The only difference is that func2 checks the result of 'addr'.
func1 always create 0 address, but func2 can function normally.
why this tiny difference can lead to different result?
I thought the create randomly maybe return 0 address due to some error. but this code says that it will always address(0) if dont check addr.

solidity compiler optimization is turned off

From solidity documentation https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/yul.html#evm-dialect

create(v, p, n) create new contract with code mem[p…(p+n)] and send v wei and return the new address returns 0 on error.

If it is returning 0 then the bytecode is failing.

I'm using the same bytecode to func1 and func2, but the results are different.

@xiabohedsky What network are you using? how much gas are used to call the functions? Can you share the bytecode? or try with a simpler contract bytecode.

The bytes are too long. Just use the Bytecode of the current contract on the "solidity compiler" tab.
I see. I'm connecting remix to local hardhat node network where this issue rises. If I change to use Remix VM, there is no issue

@xiabohedsky Were the contracts deploy? I'd suggest to try with a smaller test bytecode and increasing the gas limit. The syntax is right so it could be an error somewhere else.

I mean the bytes are too long to be pasted here. I think it's a hardhat network bug. I have created an issue here: https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/5593
